# NodeJS Deployment confusion between localhost and other domain?

Tags: node.js, heroku, port, host, codeship

I have a simple program which executes fine in localhost.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var host = "127.0.0.1";

var server = app.listen(port, host, function(){
    console.log("Server running in : ",host ," with port no : ",port);
});
```

Trying to deploy the same to heroku using codeship. Everything is building  perfect except the last line of deployment test command i.e `node index.js` which in turn is referring to **127.0.0.1** and stops deploying. May i know do i need to change something here for the **host** and **port** address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to host it successfully following through this steps

> 1. As suggested by @hunterloftis, i removed hostname.
> 2. More importantly, Procfile was missing,so added it and deployed successfully

Comment: You don't need a Procfile (unless you want one). Heroku will run `npm start` by default.

Answer (score 3):

Just don't provide a host:

```
var server = app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server listening on', port);
});
```

(This implies, "accept connections on *any* host, on this port", vs what you're trying which implies, "accept connections on 127.0.0.1 on this port")

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your app on localhost with the help of foreman that is a part of the Heroku Toolbelt. For instance:

```
foreman start web
```

You should see your app running on http://localhost:5000 or the port you have specified in your `package.json` file.

Suggest this link for further queries:
[prerequisites](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#prerequisites) to deploy a node app on Heroku?